# "Unable to resolve library include path" visual studio(visual micro)

Tags: visual-studio, arduino, include

I'm using visual studio 2013 and visual micro as add ones for arduino coding. If I run my code in arduino IDE ,code compiles fine but when I compile the same code in visual studio , it says "Unable to resolve library include path 'SPI'"
[image]

I include those libraries via visual micro and it shows all of them. So I guess it's not that my library directory is wrong. [image]

How can I solve this problem ? what may be the reason for this? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to include Library directories to library folder section in project properties->vc++ directories->libraries(may be) section. And also add include directories there too if you haven't.