# Creating a Visual Studio project from existing funky code structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was given the following code structure: there are several subfolders F1, F2, F3, and in each there is are source .cpp files and a folder includes with corresponding .h files. For example

```
[F1]
    source1.cpp
    [includes]
        source1.h
[F2]
    source2a.cpp
    source2b.cpp
    [includes]
        source2a.h
        source2b.h
[F3]
    source3.cpp
    [includes]
        source3.h
```

Moreover, e.g. in source3.cpp there may be a line

```
#include "source1.h"
```

and not

```
#include "F1/source1.h"
```

which I guess is taken care of while compiling using the make file.

I would like to create a C++ project in Visual Studio Community 2017 to use its IDE features, such as IntelliSense, etc. However, due to this funky code structure, all these includes go wrong and Visual Studio does not see the relevant headers. How can I fix this?

Comment: add the subfolders to the include path ?

Comment: @tobi303: where and how exactly can I do this? I'm a very newbie to VS.

Comment: `-Idirectory` on gcc and there must be something in in the project settings on Visual, never used it so I dont know where to find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to resolve library include path" visual studio(visual micro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672795/unable-to-resolve-library-include-path-visual-studiovisual-micro)

Comment: ^^ maybe this helps

Comment: I think your folder structure needs an edit.

Comment: @Garmekain: I can hardly disagree, however I've inherited it and not yet in power to change it.

Comment: Just suggested an edit. Hope it helps

Comment: How to: [/I (Additional Include Directories)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx):

> To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment:
>
> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
> 2. Click the C/C++
>      folder.
> 3. Click the General property page.
> 4. Modify the Additional Include Directories property.

[image]

Comment: Just to elaborate on this answer, every compiler has a set of "normal" places it looks for header files, and a way to tell it about additional places to look for header files.  As the OP guessed, the makefile is where the original code told the compiler about the additional header file locations.  This answer shows how do the same thing using the Visual Studio user interface.  You might consider looking at the makefile to identify all the include folders you need to add, and just to learn how this kind of thing works. And for the record, this is not an unusual folder layout.